# How to append a newly created QML file in .qrc file automatically?

Tags: qt, qml

I don't want to add any resources manually.Is there any way where I can set a folder to be added automatically in qrc file? Or is there any provision to add resources directly in .pro file?

Comment: If you are using Qt Creator: the .qml are automatically added to the .qrc.

Comment: If you create a new qml , then you need to manually add it in qrc file.

Comment: If you right click on the .qrc you will see a menu with one of the options is "add New", if you select it you will see a dialog where you must use the option "Qt" on the left side and then the option "QML File (Qt Quick 2) "on the right side, then another dialog appears where you put the name of the qml, then another dialog pointing to the .qrc to which it will be added, then press finish.

Comment: That's what is the manual process. 
I want to automate the same process that you told.

Comment: I think you can add your own build stage and use the script to generate a qrc file.